Unable to install PyGObject in Pycharm "meson.build:51:15: ERROR: Python dependency not found"
I'm attempting to install the PyGObject library in pycharm following this guide
https://pygobject.gnome.org/getting_started.html attempting to do step 3 on the Ubuntu / Debian section:
pip3 install pycairo

and this is what is returned:
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [48 lines of output]
      + meson setup /tmp/pip-install-9mn9tc6a/pycairo_3bd8575d46fa4c3ba97005887d18ca79 /tmp/pip-install-9mn9tc6a/pycairo_3bd8575d46fa4c3ba97005887d18ca79/.mesonpy-n59ji4fk -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md -Dwheel=true -Dtests=false --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-9mn9tc6a/pycairo_3bd8575d46fa4c3ba97005887d18ca79/.mesonpy-n59ji4fk/meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.5.2
      Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-9mn9tc6a/pycairo_3bd8575d46fa4c3ba97005887d18ca79
      Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-9mn9tc6a/pycairo_3bd8575d46fa4c3ba97005887d18ca79/.mesonpy-n59ji4fk
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pycairo
      Project version: 1.27.0
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 11.4.0 "cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.38
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Program python3 found: YES (/home/demerf/PycharmProjects/gtkgtk/.venv/bin/python)
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wall: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Warray-bounds: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wcast-align: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wconversion: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wextra: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat=2: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wimplicit-function-declaration: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Winline: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-format-attribute: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-noreturn: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpacked: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wreturn-type: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wsign-compare: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-aliasing: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-but-set-variable: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-default: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-parameter: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-strict-aliasing: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -fvisibility=hidden: YES
      Found pkg-config: YES (/usr/bin/pkg-config) 0.29.2
      Run-time dependency cairo found: YES 1.16.0
      Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried pkgconfig, pkgconfig and sysconfig)
      
      ../cairo/meson.build:51:15: ERROR: Python dependency not found
      
      A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-9mn9tc6a/pycairo_3bd8575d46fa4c3ba97005887d18ca79/.mesonpy-n59ji4fk/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS and python 3.12 and very unfamiliar with linux systems, the log file at
/tmp/pip-install-9mn9tc6a/pycairo_3bd8575d46fa4c3ba97005887d18ca79/.mesonpy-n59ji4fk/meson-logs/meson-log.txt

cannot be found. attempting to do step 4 also returns a similar error.

Unless you need a new version Ubuntu packages it (as the docs say):
sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-4.0

Otherwise don’t skip step 2:
sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev gir1.2-gtk-4.0 


after using the apt install method I'm able to run the "hello_world" script on my system but putting the script into pycharm shows that it cannot find the module "gi." I've tried running the apt install command in the terminal within the IDE assuming it has something to do with the virtual environment but it shows its already installed

Make sure pycharm is using the system python. You need to install stubs if you want it to compete modules like Gtk also.

After switching to the system interpreter it works, thanks!
